# R tmap package: basemap not working

Tags: r, openstreetmap, basemap, mapping, plot

I want to use the package tmap to plot a simple shape with a basemap (e.g. OpenStreetMap). According to the help page of tmap this should be able by using `tm_layout(basemaps = c('OpenStreetMaps'))`

For the dataset of the provinces of the Netherlands this should work

`# load package and data`

`library(tmap)
data("NLD_prov")`

`# plot  the shape by using tmap`

`tm_shape(NLD_prov) + 
  tm_polygons('population')  + 
  tm_layout(basemaps = c('OpenStreetMaps'))`

however, no basemap is showed. Also no error message is popping up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change default `tmap_mode('plot')` to `tmap_mode('view')`:

```r
library(tmap)
data("NLD_prov")

tmap_mode('view')

tm_shape(NLD_prov) + tm_polygons('population') + tm_layout(basemaps = c('OpenStreetMap'))
```

[image]

You can also call basemaps by URL:

```r
tm_shape(NLD_prov) + tm_polygons('population') + tm_layout(basemaps = 'https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}')
```

[image]

URL of OpenStreetMap is `http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`

---

### Version + live example

[image]

---

Basemaps in static plots, work-around with `ggmap` (a really basic example):

```r
library(ggmap)
library(rgeos)
library(plyr)

cn <- gCentroid(NLD_prov)

pt <- spTransform(cn, CRS('+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs '))

base_map <- get_map(coordinates(pt), maptype = "roadmap", source = "google", zoom = 7)

NLD_prov_latlong <- spTransform(NLD_prov, CRS('+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs '))

NLD_prov_latlong$id <- rownames(NLD_prov_latlong@data)

NLD <- fortify(NLD_prov_latlong, region = 'id')

NLD <- join(NLD,NLD_prov_latlong@data, by = 'id')

ggmap(base_map) + geom_polygon(data = NLD,aes(x = long,y = lat, group = group, fill = population),alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: interesting, I am doing exactly the same thing but its not working. 
What version of R and tmap are you using? I use R 3.4.1 and tmap 1.11

Comment: @user5754184 I use 3.4.3 and tmap 1.11. Check my edit

Comment: @JdP did you set `tmap_mode('view')`? Maybe is in plot mode

Comment: thanks for quick resonses. 
I Updated R but still its not working. My output is in the plot section (static) while yours is in the Viewer section (dynamic). I'm using the latest version of RStudio. any idea what can be wrong further?

Comment: @JdP plot mode, so call `tmap_mode('view')` before `map1 + tm_layout(basemaps = c('OpenStreetMap'))`

Comment: that did the trick! Thanks a lot. 
so that means basemaps are not possible for static plots?

Comment: btw aldo_tapia, then its not needed  to save the map into an new object before. 

` tm_shape(NLD_prov) + 
   tm_polygons('population') + 
   tm_layout(basemaps = c('OpenStreetMap'))
`
does the job also. so can you change the answer so that tmap_mode('view') is answer for the problem?

Comment: @JdP ready. Edited and improved with a solution for a static basemap with `ggmap`

Comment: Hi, I am not sure why I get this message: Error in tm_layout(basemaps = c("OpenStreetMap")) : unused argument (basemaps = c("OpenStreetMap")). I am using the exact same code as yours in section "Version + live example". I am using R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) on a Mac os. Thank you!

Comment: @MarcelCampion that option doesn't work nowadays, instead of `tm_layout(basemaps = c('OpenStreetMap'))` use `tm_basemap(leaflet::providers$OpenStreetMap)`